# How to parameterize the maximum of a function?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

$f(x) := -4(\frac{1}{2}-x)^2+1$

Is it possible to construct a parameterized version of $f$, say $f_a$, which fulfills:

- $f_a(0) = f_a(1) = 0$
- $f_a(a) = 1$
- $f_a'(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=a$
- $f_a''(a) < 0$
- $f_{1/2} = f$
- strictly monotonically increasing on [0,a)
- strictly monotonically decreasing on (a,1]
- $f_a$ does not have to be a polynomial necessarily
- $f_a$ is differentiable on [0,1]

[image]

I think you get the idea - just imagine a function like $f$ and visually shift the maximum along the red line while keeping anything else as (subjectively) constant as possible.

I would also be interested in learning whether this can be done numerically or if there is a systematic analytical method to achieve something like this. So I could apply this method to more complex functions. Also a definite "this is not possible because ..." would be a welcome answer.

Comment: It's definitely not possible that $f_a$ for $a\neq1/2$ is a polynomial of degree two: $f_a(0)=f_a(1)=0$ forces $f_a$ to have its extremum in $x=1/2$ in that case.

Comment: $f(x)=-(\frac12-x)^2+1$ does not have a zero at $x=0,1$.
$f(0)=-(\frac12)^2+1=\frac34$
The function you are looking for is $f(x)=-4x(x-1)$

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: Good point, I will add to my question that f does not necessarily have to be a specific function of any kind really

Comment: @cirpis: Thanks for mentioning - corrected the formula and the plot

Comment: I edited title to suppress the mention to polynomials of order 2 and answers that does not address the OP's edited concern.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_a(x) = c_1x^2 + c_2x + c_3$. Since $f_a(0) = 0$, $c_3 = 0$. Since $f_a(1) = 0$, $c_1 = -c_2$. Therefore, $$f_a(x) = c_1(x^2 - x)$$

Since $f_a(a) = 1$, therefore $c_1(a^2 - a) = 1$, i.e. $c_1 = \frac{1}{a^2 - a}$. Therefore, $$f_a(x) = \frac{1}{a^2 - a}(x^2 - x)$$

Now, $f_a'(x) = \frac{1}{a^2 - a}(2x - 1)$. For $f_a'(a) = 0$, $a$ has to be equal to 1/2. Doesn't look there is any other choice :-/

Comment: yes, but what if the function was of order higher than $2$? Its was not specified that the function need be of order two, just that the special case of $f_{\frac12}$ be of order two.

Comment: @cirpis the title says degree two polynomial

Comment: sorry for the confusion - I in fact just assumed the degree two to refer to the special case not necessarily to the final f.  Essentially a polynomial is defined by its zeros of course - but still thanks for the math clarification.

Comment: For the sake of clarity: a non zero polynomial in ${\mathbb R}[x]$ is characterized, up to multiplication by a nonzero real number,  by its *complex* roots and their multiplicity.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1-(x-a)^2/a^2, x<a\\1-(x-a)^2/(1-a)^2, x\ge a\end{cases}$$

It is differentiable, but unfortunately it has no second derivative at $x=a$.